# Protractor Element text value sendKeys and attribute error

Tags: angularjs, angular, attributes, protractor, sendkeys

i've been trying to run this code in protractor but i keep getting this error also i can't find a way to get the anpr_box_input text value anyhow.

Value: ManagedPromise::871 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}
    failed - should have a valid license number plate when screen contains as ANPR request
  Suite failed: ANPR Screen Content

Chrome version: 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
Dependencies:
"protractor": "5.1.2",
"jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"

describe('ANPR Screen Content', function () {

```
it('should have a valid license number plate when screen contains as ANPR request', function () {

    var base_keyboard_ok = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('base-keyboard-ok'));

    var anpr_box_input = browser.driver.findElement(by.className('anpr-box-input'));
    //anpr_box_input.clear().then(function() { anpr_box_input.sendKeys('999'); }); tryed it before, didn't work
    anpr_box_input.clear().then(function() { anpr_box_input.setAttribute("value", "459"); });

    base_keyboard_ok.click();

    /* didn't work       
    anpr_box_input.getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log("AQUI: " + text);
    });
    */

    //console.log("Value: " + anpr_box_input.getAttribute('value')); didn't work

    //working on..
    anpr_box_input.getAttribute('value').then(function(text) {
        console.log("Value: " + text);
    });

    //so i'll need something like
    expect(anpr_box_input.text).toEqual("1234"); 
});
```

});

Comment: The section for the html comes out just like it:

Comment: <div _ngcontent-c9="" class="anpr-box-input" fxlayoutalign="center center" ng-reflect-align="center center" ng-reflect-class-base="anpr-box-input" style="justify-content: center; align-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-pack: center; -webkit-box-align: center; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; -webkit-box-direction: normal;"></div>

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Tryed this one as well but nothing happend

Comment: anpr_box_input.getAttribute('innerHTML').then(function(text) {
    console.log("Value: " + text);
});

Comment: Can u paste the error your facing?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided info and HTML you can't set the value of the element with

`anpr_box_input.sendKeys('999');` because it is not an `input`, it's a `<div>`.

`anpr_box_input.setAttribute("value", "459");` will also not work because `setAttribute` is not a valid Protractor command. You first need to know how the field works, my guess is that it's a `<div>` element that reflects the value of an other field that contains the original value. You need to locate that field and do a:

- `sendKeys()`
- `browser.driver.executeScript('argument[0].setAttribute("name", "value")', element(by.css('#selector').getWebElement())`

on it.

I also have 1 remark on you code. Based on the code you provided it looks like you have an Angular page, but you are using "vanila" webdriver commands to locate the elements, why don't you use the Protractor syntax with `element(by.css(''))` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much wswebcreation, i'll have a look on what you've just mentioned about the vanila webdriver but i've just found a solution just as follows:

```
it('should have a valid license number plate when screen contains as ANPR request', function () { 
    var buttonKey;

    buttonKey = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('button_A')); 
    buttonKey.click();

    browser.sleep(SLEEP_TIMER);

    buttonKey = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('button_B'));
    buttonKey.click();

    var base_keyboard_ok = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('base-keyboard-ok'));
    base_keyboard_ok.click();

    var anpr_box_input = browser.driver.findElement(by.className('anpr-box-input'));
    anpr_box_input.getAttribute('innerHTML').then(function(anpr) {
        console.log("Plate: " + anpr);
        expect(globalE2EFunctions.validateAnpr(anpr)).toBe(true);
    });

});

module.exports = {

  //Still need to implement regex plates validation according to each country patterns
  validateAnpr: function(anpr) {
    if(anpr != 'CANCEL' && anpr != 'DEL' && anpr != 'OK'){
      return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
  }

};
```